# Can anyone assist with "The name 'posttype' does not exist in the current context" error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

.......So, I have the below class which I have created as part of my automated test pack, but I am getting an error against the 'ListPostsPage.GoTo(PostType.Page)' line of code, advising that: 'the name PostType does not exist in the current context'. The code for this class is below:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WordpressTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PageTests
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        Driver.Initialise();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CanEditAPage()
    {
        LoginPage.GoTo();
        LoginPage.LoginAs("XXXXXX").WithPassword("XXXXXX").Login();

        **ListPostsPage.GoTo(PostType.Page);**
        ListPostsPage.SelectPost("Sample Page");

        Assert.IsTrue(NewPostPage.IsInEditMode(), "Wasn't in edit mode");
        Assert.AreEqual("Sample Page", NewPostPage.Title, "Title did not match");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        Driver.Close();
    }
   }
}
```

Just for reference, the code for the ListPostsPage class is as follows:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WordpressTests
{
    public class ListPostsPage
{
    public static void GoTo(PostType postType)
    {
        switch (postType)
        {
            case PostType.Page:
                Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("menu-pages")).Click();
                Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.LinkText("All Pages")).Click();
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void SelectPost(string title)
    {
        var postLink = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sample Page"));
        postLink.Click();
    }

    public enum PostType
    {
        Page
    }

  }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the issue may be? Please bear in mind I am fairly new to this, so please be nice! :-)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Andy

Comment: As a point I'd like to point out you'd benefit greatly from implementing the page object model using Selenium. Everything is `static` in your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PostType` is an enum member of `ListPostsPage` but you're trying to access it as if it were a static class.

You should do this:

```
ListPostsPage.GoTo(ListPostsPage.PostType.Page);
```